# How do I declare a variable type vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

The following throws an error with or with out `Option Explicit` set.

Create a file named `dim.vbs`.

```
Dim a as String
```

Then run at the command prompt.

```
cscript dim.vbs
```

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

Is there a way to force the variable type with or with out `Option Explicit` set?

Comment: @BigBen how do I run VBA from the command line then?

Comment: You don't. VBA is hosted.

Comment: VBA is not VBScript. They're very different languages. VBScript is a front-end language for the ActiveScripting engine and does not support typed variables.

Comment: `Dim a` is the *only* thing you can do in Vbscript. It only has one data type.

Comment: @BigBen VBScript does have data-types, they're just not exposed to the programmer.

Comment: @Dai - yeah semantics shemantics lol, point taken. "One data type" is sloppy on my part.

Comment: @BigBen if I add OptionExplicit it seems to run vba code seamlessly.  Back to the question is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Lime Please post the VBA code that you say runs "seamlessly" in VBScript.

Comment: ^ Clearly `Dim a As String` *doesn't* work in VBScript so the claim that VBA code "runs seamlessly" must mean you either didn't declare your variables or declared them without a type and as such you "got lucky." As mentioned by @Dai, VBscript does not support typed variables, which answers your question.

Comment: @BigBen you are right.  Sigh Is there a guide to converting VBA to VBScript or automated way it would be nice.

Comment: @Lime Semantic-preserving automatic program conversion is a holy-grail of computer-science and software engineering (especially inter-paradigm automatic program conversion) - if you do find or build such a tool you would become very rich and famous overnight.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I declare a variable type in vbscript?

You can't.

- VBScript does not support the concept of statically-typed variables.
- VBScript is a frontend language for Windows' ActiveScripting environment.

  - This environment is hosted by `cscript` (for the command-line) and `wscript` (when you don't want a CMD window to appear).
  - The environment is also hosted by IIS for Classic ASP `.asp`/`.asa`, and formerly Internet Explorer (prior to Internet Explorer 9) where it was the basis for its JavaScript engine.

    - "JScript" is the brand (or dialect) of JavaScript also supported by ActiveScripting: both VBScript and JScript share similarities in what they're both capable of.
- ActiveScripting is intended for working with COM objects.

VBScript's **syntax** is a subset of VBA's and largely mutually intelligible because VBA will implicitly type variables without a static type definition as a COM `Variant` object, which is roughly equivalent (and possibly identical, I forget) to the real underlying type used by VBScript's variables.

(Internally VBScript *is* typed: otherwise it would be impossible for VBScript to use COM. You can tell there's some typing under-the-hood because of how you need to use the `Set` and `Let` keywords based on the expected type of a value, or how you can only use `Const` in VBScript with certain literal value types, and so on).

By analogy: you have a driver's license for a passenger-car (you know how to write VBA) and you decide to drive a forklift truck (VBScript) - because you know how to drive a passenger-car and because the controls/interface looks the same (it's got a steering wheel, a handbrake, a driver's seat, a speedometer) that your skills as a passenger-car driver mean you should be able to drive a forklift truck immediately and without any problems. You can't and you won't: forklift trucks handle very differently (e.g. rear-wheel steering, electric drive, and many regions [require specialty licensing for forklift truck drivers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJYOkZz6Dck) for this reason).

Comment: That analogy though. Spot on, made my evening :-) Sounds like Michael from The Office.

Comment: "Internally VBSCript is typed" - hence `TypeName` also, besides the examples you give.

Comment: @BigBen Correct. It's VBScript's equivalent to JavaScript's `typeof` operator.

Comment: @Lime The other answer that you accepted just now does not contradict anything in my answer. Their answer shows that VBScript does have value-typing *internally* (which I said too!) but their answer goes into more detail, but it does not answer your question any more than mine does - and that answer still agrees with me on the main point in your question which is that VBScript does **not allow you to declare variables with a static type**.

Comment: This appears to not tell the whole story*

Comment: @Lime If you had asked how VBScript's typing system worked in your question I would have provided the same detail. I agree the other answer provided useful insight and examples, but neither my answer nor theirs provides the "whole story". Your question was very short and light on details - I feel you're being arbitrary.

Comment: Tbh @dai, shouldn't have been answered full stop and should have been [flagged as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855633/vbscript-error-when-declaring-any-variable-with-its-required-data-types). I personally upvoted your answer because it's a very technical detailed answer, unfortunately, it's wasted here. Maybe re-post it on the dup target?

Comment: @Lankymart If I marked this question as a duplicate I wouldn't have earned the +4 votes I've got so far :D (btw, I have also upvoted your answer (as did someone else), but 2 other people downvoted you, that's why your answer is at zero)). Also it's 5:52am here, I don't want to think about it :D

Comment: @Lankymart Derp. I just realised you aren't brandongoodman - nvm

Answer (score 0):

Although its **not** possible to declare variables with specific types in VBS as you would in VB or VBA, there *are* several conversion functions that will ensure that your variable contain the data type that you desire.

```
CBool, CByte, CCur, CDate, CDbl, CInt, CLng, CSng, CStr
```

for instance

```
Option Explicit
Dim x
x = "1"
WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
x = CInt("1")
WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
x = CInt(1)
WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
```

produces

```
String
Integer
Integer
```

Just beware that passing unconvertable values into a conversion function may cause Type mismatch errors.  For instance, a string like "x9x" cannot be converted to a number so CInt("x9x") will cause a runtime error that halts execution.

Comment: Been [covered years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3281355/692942).

Comment: And [still again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829296/692942).

Comment: And [yet again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737469/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart yes but it answers the question

Comment: @Lime Yes, the same question, for the nth time.